# prevent iPAD scrolling while allowing list scrolling

Tags: javascript, ipad, touch

I need to disable the default iPAD scrolling (via capturing touchmove on the body) but still allow a list on my page to scroll.

I tried:

```
$('body').on('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
$('itemList').on('touchmove', function(e) { alert('hi'); e.stopPropagation(); });
```

But it seems that itemList's touchmove is not being called at all. on the iPAD nothing gets scrolled.

see http://jsfiddle.net/e8dcJ

Any ideas how to solve this ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe don't apply the event to the body, which covers everything.  Instead, apply the event to a the various elements you want to prevent scrolling.  Alternately, wrap everything in a DIV except the list and then set the position to fixed and add the event.